# How do I keep my rvm gemset while using tmux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, tmux

I have a .rvmrc file in my project directory (let's call it `/GameScores`). It will load a gemset named `GameScores` when I move into that directory. This part works fine.

But while in `/GameScores`, as soon as I go into tmux my terminal is no longer using the `GameScores` gemset. If I do `rvm gemset name` I get a blank

Any idea how to fix this? I want to be able to keep using my gemset when I use tmux. My current workaround is to simply run `rvm gemset use GameScores` when I go into tmux but I don't want to do that every time.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If I `cd` into a directory with a `.rvmrc`, the gemset switch happens, but if I then enter a tmux session, the gemset is still chosen. What version of rvm are you using? (rvm 1.6.4 here; tmux 1.4)

Comment: rvm 1.2.4. Let me go update :)  Ok, I'm on 1.6.4 and tmux 1.4 and the same thing happens. No gemset changes, still empty. (I restarted my terminal to make sure to use 1.6.4 after installing). I'm also using zsh on mac osx.

Comment: Maybe it's a zsh interaction? I'm using Bash, and that seems to be the only difference between us. If nobody here can answer, try #rvm on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: Tried with bash and still have the same issue. Yep, time to hit up #rvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix for this is to `cd .` after starting tmux. This is the answer provided by Wayne, the author of rvm.

Edit 1:
If the above does not work you can do:

```
cd ..;cd -
```

This is essentially the same as `cd .`

`cd ..` takes you up one dir

`cd -` takes you back

Comment: this actually doesn't work for me anymore. so i am doing `cd ..;1` now in zsh

Comment: cd ..;1 at the bottom of my .zshrc was spot on. Works well.

Comment: I'm curious what that "1" is supposed to do.   It gives me "zsh: command not found: 1"

Comment: @JonathandelStrother `1` goes back to the previous dir. `2` goes back to the one before that, etc. I'm using oh-my-zsh and maybe it's provided by that and not zsh itself?

Answer (score 3):

`cd .` does not work for me, but this will work in zsh and bash:

```
cd ..;cd -
```

Just put it at the bottom of `.zshrc` / `.bashrc` etc.

- rvm 1.22.3
- tmux 1.8
- zsh 5.0.2

Comment: In case anyone else finds this - now that rvm sources itself from .zlogin, I had to put this in my .zlogin file rather than .zshrc.